# Blind SQL Injection

Tags: web-application, sql-injection

I am participating in a program that when I write in the url parameter `' or 1=1;--` it gives me Forbidden 403 and when I write in the parameter `' or 1=2;--` it shows me the page.

Is the website and parameter vulnerable?

If yes is it a blind SQL?

If it is a blind SQL how can I exploit it further?

Comment: You have probably hit a WAF which is refusing execution of the `OR 1=1` payload.

Comment: It's only blind sql if there is an error that is not being displayed. And it sounds like you don't have enough info to determine one way or another.

Comment: The 403 status indeed makes it look like a filter rejecting what looks like an attack attempt. But the specificity makes me wonder whether it will also stop `' or 69=69;--`, `' or 218<>114;--`, `' or 'a'='a';--` and other similar equivalent attempts not involving `1=1`. You could also try some not involving `or` like `' is not null;--`.

Comment: The WAF probably has the string `1=1` blacklisted

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a firewall blocked you, that is why you get 403
cuz ' or 1=1;-- is a dangerous traffic

try detect WAF using nmap script

nmap –script=http-waf-fingerprint testsite.com